# odd behavior of pgrep in bash script

Tags: macos, bash, jenkins, grep

I have a script to kill a process tree that works fine in linux but I am experiencing some odd behaviour on osx. It actually works fine with my unit tests and also when trying to run it manually on osx, but for some reason when it runs as a jenkins job it acts differently.

So this is the current bash function with a bit of debug echo and sleeps:

```
killtree() {
  local _pid=$1
  local _sig=${2:--TERM}
  echo "Stopping ${_pid}"
  sleep 1
  kill -stop ${_pid} # stop parent to avoid creation of new children
  children=`pgrep -P ${_pid}`
  echo "Children=$children"
  sleep 1
  for _child in $children; do
      killtree ${_child} ${_sig}
  done
  echo "Killing child ${_pid}"
  sleep 1
  kill -${_sig} ${_pid}
}
```

The call to pgrep that from a failing run can be `pgrep -P 9651` prints out all processes on the machine, and the scripts hangs when it try to kill pid 0.

But why would it get all processes ? When the run is done process 9651 is still running and if I issue the command on the command line `pgrep -P 9651` there is no output at all (which is expected since this process should have no children).

The process that is trying to be killed is in this case a simple `sleep 10` that is used for testing.

I added a debug call to print the process tree right before listing children:

```
+ pstree='-+= 00001 root /sbin/launchd
 \-+= 09774 root /usr/sbin/sshd -i
   \-+- 09777 jenkins /usr/sbin/sshd -i
     \-+= 09783 jenkins bash -c cd '\''/var/jenkins'\'' && java  -jar slave.jar
       \-+- 09784 jenkins /usr/bin/java -jar slave.jar
         \-+- 09807 jenkins /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -classpath/     
          \-+- 09817 jenkins /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java -
            \--- 09828 jenkins sleep 10'
```

Looks normal to me, the `sleep 10` have no children.

Any ideas - I am a bit stuck after having tried to debug this for some hours ?

(Actually posted first on apple.stackexchange since I saw it only on osx, but this might be a better place for it since I pgrep does not even exist on osx by default)

Comment: Please include the origin of the pgrep you use.  Is it [Homebrew](http://brew.sh)?

Comment: @HenkLangeveld Yes, it's from "brew install proctools" and it's version "stable 0.4pre1".

Comment: Just a wild guess, Try putting the full system path to the pgrep command in the script.  It may be running with a different environment PATH.  I believe the other commands should be interpreted natively by the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some searching reveals that jenkins runs tasks under a modified environment PATH (probably for security reasons).  You will need to insure that:

- pgrep is installed on your system (older OSX versions don't have it,  it is available in the Apple Developer's Tools)
- pgrep is in the path.

Alternatively,  if you have difficulty modifying the PATH under jenkins you can edit the script to include the full pgrep path

first determine where your pgrep is running under a user tty shell:

```
$ which pgrep
/opt/local/bin/pgrep
```

Change:

```
children=`pgrep -P ${_pid}`
```

To:

```
children=`/opt/local/bin/pgrep -P ${_pid}`
```

The other shell commands (echo, sleep, kill, etc...) should be interpreted natively by the command shell and 'should' not require pathing.

Comment: pgrep is installed and runs since it prints pids - but I think you might be right about the path issue. I can see that there are actually multiple pgrep on this system. So it might use the wrong one. I'll check if it's indeed not using the one the script expect.

Comment: It was indeed using another one (origin NetBSD) while the script expected the proctools version. Thanks. (Can't award the bounty for another 5 hours for some reason)

Comment: It appears that Jenkins is configuring cron underneath.  Glad this helped.